# TypeError: 'numpy.longlong' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp

For a current project, I am running a number of loops through a Pandas DataFrame to detect the most common word pairs (bigrams) in the set. The output `freq` is indicating how many times each bigram has been found.

As a next step, I would like to sum up the `freq` numbers received. The command `sum(freq)` is however yielding the following output:  `TypeError: 'numpy.longlong' object is not iterable`.

Does anyone know how I can sum up the numbers/how to solve the error?

```
# Analysis loops through different qualitative sections
for i in ['Text_Pro','Text_Con','Text_Main']:
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram_Group1(df[i], 500)
    for word, freq in common_words:
        print(word, freq, sum(freq))
```

Comment: This error says that `freq` is a long number and you can't perform a`sum` over a number

Comment: Thanks a lot - the numbers should be very basic integers like 20, 5, 1. Do you know any way to sum up the numbers in the given case?

Comment: Could you try `sum([freq for word, freq in common_words])`

Comment: Nailed it, many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Glad I could help :). I have added the answer as it might be helpful to other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was `freq` is a number, and you can't perform a `sum()` function over a number. So, the way to fix it is to do the following:

```
sum([freq for word, freq in common_words])
```

Instead of:

```
for word, freq in common_words:
    print(word, freq, sum(freq))
```